# Configuring log4j with different verbosity

Tags: java, log4j, configuration-files

i have a problem with log4j

I want a solution which in console I have only INFO log, and in specific files another verbosity level (like DEBUG)

this is my configuration:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c] [%C{1}.%M:%L] %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="PP" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
    <param name="File" value="log/polling_processor.log"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="TRACE"/><!-- OFF FATAL ERROR WARN INFO DEBUG TRACE ALL -->

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c] [%C{1}.%M:%L] %m%n"/><!-- "%d %-5p [%c] %m%n" -->
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="TR" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
    <param name="File" value="log/trasmission.log"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="TRACE"/><!-- OFF FATAL ERROR WARN INFO DEBUG TRACE ALL -->

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c] [%C{1}.%M:%L] %m%n"/><!-- "%d %-5p [%c] %m%n" -->
    </layout>
</appender>

<category name="POLLING_PROCESSOR">
    <priority value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="PP"/>
</category> 

<category name="TRASMISSION">
    <priority value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="TR"/>
</category> 

<root>
    <level value="info"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</root>
```

but i don't know why, in console I have the same verbosity that I have configured into category tag (debug)

where is my error?

Comment: Do you also have a `<appender>` named "CONSOLE"?

Comment: ups...i'm sorry, I cutted off -_-'...Yes I have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you would want to have the root logger log at debug level, but limit the appender to info.

How about adding the

```
<param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
```

to the console appender